# How to remove and re-add an object to a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, javascript-objects, indexof

I am building a language learning app which displays flash cards to the user. I want the user to be able to select cards they have learned and be able to display them on a separate page. For this to work I am trying to add a card to an array onClick, and then remove it from the array on a second click, and I then want them to be able to re-add it again later. I can then take the data in the array and display it somewhere else.

I'm using react hooks and currently have an empty global array and a function:

```
const learnedCards = [];

addRemoveCard = () => {
  setIsLearned(!isLearned);

  const getCard = {
    character: character,
    pinyin: pinyin,
    english: english,
    type: type,
  };

  learnedCards.push(getCard);

  if (isLearned) {
    let stringifyCards = learnedCards.map(JSON.stringify);
    let res = stringifyCards.filter(
      (a, _, aa) => aa.indexOf(a) === aa.lastIndexOf(a)
    );
    let updatedLearnedCards = Array.from(res).map(JSON.parse);
    console.log(updatedLearnedCards);
  }
};
```

Pushing cards on the first click is easy enough, what I am struggling with is finding a way to remove and re-add them again. The code above shows my current attempt which works in removing the card the first time, but does not allow the user to then re-add the card again later. I tried resetting the variable `res` to null but that didn't help. Does anyone know of a way I can resolve this?

Comment: Remove with [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Re-add with `push()`, `splice()` or `unshift()` depending on where you want to re-add

Comment: I should have mentioned that I do not know the index of the object I want to remove

Comment: The many ways of adding and removing JS array elements are very well documented. Your problem is in your algorithm, not in JS array handling.